# How to create lucene query which should give objects that only matches two given value with given two field?

Tags: hibernate, lucene, infinispan

I am using infinispan cache for distribution.We have scenerio like have to get objects based on exact field value.So,we tried lucene .

scenerio like value matches with any field should give object.For that, we have written follow.it is working fine

```
SearchManager searchManager = Search.getSearchManager(indexingCache);
QueryBuilder queryBuilder = searchManager.buildQueryBuilderForClass(IndexingCallData.class).get();
org.apache.lucene.search.Query luceneQuery = queryBuilder.phrase()
                          .onField("callerName").matching("6000")                         
                         .andField("calleeName").matching(filedValue)
                          .andField("callerNameForDisplay")
                          .andField("gatewayIdIngress")
                          .andField("gatewayIdEgress")
                          .andField("originalCalleeName")
                          .sentence("any value here")
                          .createQuery();
```

But,dont know how to write query like  exact matches with two different field with appropriate value.I saw some example like follow

```
org.apache.lucene.search.Query luceneQuery = searchManager.buildQueryBuilderForClass(IndexingCallData.class)
            .get()
            .keyword()        
            .onField("callerName").matching("6000")         
            .createQuery();
```

Here How to add one more condition?? .can anyone help me out please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution. that is,

```
org.apache.lucene.search.Query subluceneQuery = searchManager.buildQueryBuilderForClass(IndexingCallData.class)
            .get()
            .keyword()        
            .onField("callerName").matching("sipp")                     
            .createQuery();

         org.apache.lucene.search.Query subluceneQuery2 = searchManager.buildQueryBuilderForClass(IndexingCallData.class)
            .get()
            .keyword()        
            .onField("calleeName").matching(filedValue)                     
            .createQuery();

        org.apache.lucene.search.Query luceneQuery = searchManager.buildQueryBuilderForClass(IndexingCallData.class)
            .get()
            .bool()                         
            .must(subluceneQuery)
            .must(subluceneQuery2)
            .createQuery();
```